# Laravel not showing icons in shared hosting with Git

Tags: php, laravel, favicon

I have a problem in my website, where the icons wont show up, but other images and all the CSS works fine. I noticed that if I changed the name of the icon file, it would work. But whenever I reverted the changes, the icon disappeared again. I deployed my project on a shared hosting site, and checked the permissions which is 775 for all the project files (because someone pointed out that might be the reason).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{!! asset('storage/favicon.ico') !!}" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

Any idea on what is causing this? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you shere path you provided for icon file link?

Comment: already updated, sir @IrshadKhan